# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument : Loading a large json file in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am getting the error

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

while loading a large json file around 7 gb. using `json.load` 
It is a nested dictionary. Can anyone suggest any idea other than ijson?

Comment: Need to see some code! @Nimesh